# How to filter on one column, then filter on the next, then another and copy the total of all three filters?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been struggling with filtering three columns and taking whatever comes up from each of the three columns (combined) and copying it all. So, if column one returns 1 row and column 2 return 2 rows and column 3 returns 1 row. Then I want to see all 5 rows at one time and copy them. The code doesn't seem to work when there is no data that comes up in the filter. So, I'm thinking I need an if then statement, but for some reason it gives me an error "Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" at the .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor

Thanks so much in advance for any help you have! I've been working all day trying out code to fix this error.Here's the code.

```
Sub FilterDifferences()

 'Filtering by differences
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngK As Range
Dim rngL As Range
Dim rngM As Range
Dim Lrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    '~~> Get last row of Col M
    Lrow = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Identify the range
    Set rng = .Range("A1:M" & Lrow)

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Identify the range in Col K Which has red font

    With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
    Set rngK = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    .AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Identify the range in Col L Which has red font
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
    Set rngL = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

  .AutoFilterMode = False

            '~~> Identify the range in Col M Which has red font
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
    Set rngM = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False

    '~~> Hide All except the Header row
    rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    '~~> Unhide the rows which have red font
    Union(rngK, rngL, rngM).EntireRow.Hidden = False

 End With

'Copying differences and putting them into a file
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, you cannot filter on all 3 first then copy them all, since it's an `OR` condition across multiple columns. You have to copy the 1 from column 1 first, the 2 from column 2 2nd and the 1 from column 3 third. Or, you can create a formula based helper column that figures out if column 1, 2 or 3 is red and filter based on that before copying.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. I found some code to help me with that and created different rng names to union them all at the end. Sadly, I can't get past the first column filter line though.

Comment: Can you replicate the first filter manually now? I mean, can you do it manually in the Excel Interface without code?

Comment: Yes, I can manually filter each row in the Excel interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're getting an error, as your code works perfectly on Excel 2007 here, *even if* the entire table contains no red font cells. The only time I get an error is if there is no data in the table at all.

That said, the following is how you trap and ignore errors:

```
With rng
  .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rngK = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngK Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error filtering Col K"
  End If
End With
```

You can check that an error occurred by checking if the range is `Nothing`.

---

**EDIT:**

The only reason I can think of that you are getting errors, is that you have a corrupted workbook or corrupted Excel.

You could try creating a new workbook and copy/pasting the VBA code and table data into it and see if that fixes the issue.

For problems with Excel itself try the following:

1. Start Excel in safe mode to eliminate AddIn issues.
2. Try repairing Excel.
3. Try reinstalling Office.

Note that each of the above steps may not fix the faulty workbook, but a newly create workbook might work.

With respect to your new working code (excluding the use of `With ws` and `With rng`) if you are **correctly** wrapping ***all three*** of the `.SpecialCells...` lines with the error trapping technique, there is *no way* any of the ranges could be `Nothing` when you get to the `Union`.

---

I have also included three code examples for you to try. All three work correctly in my version of Excel, *even with no data at all in the table*.

The first one is your original code with a better "last row" algorithm, the three column checks rolled up into a loop, and the elimination of all unnecessary variables:

```
Sub FilterDifferences1()

   'Filtering by differences
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rngUnion As Range
  Dim varColNum As Variant
  Dim Lrow As Long

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Get last row of Col M (Need to use Match() as .End(xlUp).Row only finds the last visible row
    Set rng = .Range("M:M")
    With WorksheetFunction
      On Error Resume Next
        Lrow = 1
        Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match(1E+306, rng, 1))
        Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match("*", rng, -1))
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~> Identify the range and use it
    With .Range("A1:M" & Lrow)
      .EntireRow.Hidden = False

      '~~> Build up range of every Col Which has red font
      Set rngUnion = .Rows(1)
      For Each varColNum In Array(11, 12, 13)
        '~~> Identify the range in current Col Which has red font
        .AutoFilter Field:=varColNum, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
        Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        .AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows
      Next varColNum

      '~~> Hide All except the Header row
      .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True

      '~~> Unhide the rows which have red font
      rngUnion.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With

    'Copying differences and putting them into a file
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
  End With

End Sub
```

The second one is your new working code (as well as I understand) with only the better "last row" algorithm added:

```
Sub FilterDifferences2()

   'Filtering by differences
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rngK As Range
  Dim rngL As Range
  Dim rngM As Range
  Dim Lrow As Long

  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

  '~~> Get last row of Col M (Need to use Match() as .End(xlUp).Row only finds the last visible row
  Set rng = Range("M:M")
  With WorksheetFunction
    On Error Resume Next
      Lrow = 1
      Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match(1E+306, rng, 1))
      Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match("*", rng, -1))
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With

  '~~> Identify the range and use it
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).EntireRow.Hidden = False

  '~~> Identify the range in Col K Which has red font
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
'  On Error Resume Next
    Set rngK = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngK Is Nothing Then
    Set rngK = Range("A1:M1")
  End If
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows

  '~~> Identify the range in Col L Which has red font
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rngL = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngL Is Nothing Then
    Set rngL = Range("A1:M1")
  End If
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows

  '~~> Identify the range in Col M Which has red font
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rngM = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If rngM Is Nothing Then
    Set rngM = Range("A1:M1")
  End If
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows

  '~~> Hide All except the Header row
  Range("A1:M" & Lrow).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True

  '~~> Unhide the rows which have red font
  On Error Resume Next
    Union(rngK, rngL, rngM).EntireRow.Hidden = False
  On Error GoTo 0

  'Copying differences and putting them into a file
  ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
  Selection.Copy

End Sub
```

The last one is your new working code with the better "last row" algorithm, the three column checks rolled up into a loop, and the elimination of all unnecessary variables:

```
Sub FilterDifferences3()

   'Filtering by differences
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rngUnion As Range
  Dim varColNum As Variant
  Dim Lrow As Long

  With Sheets("Sheet1")
    '~~> Get last row of Col M (Need to use Match() as .End(xlUp).Row only finds the last visible row
    Set rng = .Range("M:M")
    With WorksheetFunction
      On Error Resume Next
        Lrow = 1
        Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match(1E+306, rng, 1))
        Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match("*", rng, -1))
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~> Identify the range and use it
    With Range("A1:M" & Lrow)
      .EntireRow.Hidden = False

      '~~> Build up range of every Col Which has red font
      Set rngUnion = Range("A1:M1")
      For Each varColNum In Array(11, 12, 13)
        '~~> Identify the range in current Col Which has red font
        .AutoFilter Field:=varColNum, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
        On Error Resume Next
          Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows
      Next varColNum

      '~~> Hide All except the Header row
      .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True

      '~~> Unhide the rows which have red font
      rngUnion.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With

    'Copying differences and putting them into a file
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
  End With

End Sub

Sub FilterDifferences3a()

   'Filtering by differences
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim aarng As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rngK As Range
  Dim rngL As Range
  Dim rngM As Range
  Dim Lrow As Long

  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

  With ws
    '~~> Get last row of Col M (Need to use Match() as .End(xlUp).Row only finds the last visible row
    Set rng = .Range("M:M")
    With WorksheetFunction
      On Error Resume Next
        Lrow = 1
        Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match(1E+306, rng, 1))
        Lrow = .Max(Lrow, .Match("*", rng, -1))
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~> Identify the range and use it
    With Range("A1:M" & Lrow)
      .EntireRow.Hidden = False

      '~~> Identify the range in Col K Which has red font
      .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
      On Error Resume Next
        Set rngK = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If rngK Is Nothing Then Set rngK = Range("A1:M1")
      .AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows

      '~~> Identify the range in Col L Which has red font
      .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
      On Error Resume Next
        Set rngL = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If rngL Is Nothing Then Set rngL = Range("A1:M1")
      .AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows

      '~~> Identify the range in Col M Which has red font
      .AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
      On Error Resume Next
        Set rngM = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      On Error GoTo 0
      If rngM Is Nothing Then Set rngM = Range("A1:M1")
      .AutoFilter ' Turns AutoFilter off and shows all rows

      '~~> Hide All except the Header row
      .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Hidden = True

      '~~> Unhide the rows which have red font
      Union(rngK, rngL, rngM).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With

    'Copying differences and putting them into a file
    .UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have no idea why I'm getting the error either. I could've sworn this exact code worked the other day. Now, It stops consistently at the .Autofilter line. I tried your code, but it won't even get to it because the error happens on the line before.

Comment: @SoSincere3 To fix the error issue try the following (in order of least drastic to most) 1) Start Excel in safe mode to eliminate AddIn issues. 2)  Create a new workbook. Manually copy paste everything across. 3) Try repairing Excel. If that fails to fix the issue, repeat step 2. 4) Reinstall Office. If that fails, repeat step 2 %) Still working out the details of this one.

Comment: Ok. For some reason it works fine if I don't use With ws and With rng. So, I ended up using this code. I'm good now until I get to the union and it doesn't work because the ranges may equal nothing.
        Range("A1:M" & Lrow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(192, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngK = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range("A1:M" & Lrow).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If rngK Is Nothing Then
        Set rngK = Range("A1:M1")
        End If

Comment: @SoSincere3 When you eliminated the `With ws` and `With rng` you also effectively changed `ws.Range()` to `Application.Range()` in some places, and `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range()` in others. That could be why it works now. If you've used the error trapping correctly, there's *no way* the ranges could be equal to nothing when you get to the `Union`. See the update in the answer for more details on this and the other error issues

Comment: @ RobinCTS So, I've tried all of the code that you posted and still got errors. The first two were giving me an error at the same spot as my original issue. The third one did not give me an error but it only hid row 2 (when it was supposed to be hiding all except the header row). Then the union never showed up.

Comment: I ended up trying a function from a website (cpearson.com/excel/BetterUnion.aspx). Then I kept my code mostly the same. Now, when I get to the part where I want to unhide the Union, it errors saying there's an object error.            
               '~~> Unhide the rows which have red font
       Set RR = Union2(rngK, rngL, rngM)
        
        ActiveSheet.Range("RR").EntireRow.Hidden = False

Comment: @SoSincere3 Seems like on your computer,  the `Union()` function is broken. what version of Excel are you using? Are you running on Windows or OS X?

Comment: I found that the problem was that I was trying to run the code from a class module (the one with the workbook icon). When I copied the exact same original code into a new module the original code I posted worked.

Comment: @SoSincere3 Good to hear! Next time somebody has an un-replicable problem I'll remember to ask "Do you have the code in a standard module, and not a class/excel object module" :) Hopefully you got some useful tips from my examples anyways.